# Returning a Pointer to a Multidimensional Array

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, return-value

I'd like to use the following function to return a transposed pointer to a multidimensional array.

**Code**

```
float** Matrix3f::Transpose( void )
{

    float matrix[MATRIX3_DIMS][MATRIX3_DIMS] =
    {
        { mMatrix[ 0 ][ 0 ], mMatrix[ 1 ][ 0 ], mMatrix[ 2 ][ 0 ] },
        { mMatrix[ 0 ][ 1 ], mMatrix[ 1 ][ 1 ], mMatrix[ 2 ][ 1 ] },
        { mMatrix[ 0 ][ 2 ], mMatrix[ 1 ][ 2 ], mMatrix[ 2 ][ 2 ] }
    };

    float** ret = new float*[ MATRIX3_DIMS ];

    for ( int i = 0; i < MATRIX3_DIMS; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < MATRIX3_DIMS; j++ )
        {
            ( *ret )[ i ][ j ] = matrix[ i ][ j ];
        }
    }

    return ret;

}
```

**Description**

As shown, I declare a multidimensional array using initialization syntax(using the class-member matrix - mMatrix - to create a transposed version of the matrix itself. I then assign a multidimensional pointer to an array (ret) and loop through, assigning each member of the local array - matrix - to the ret pointer array.

The error I receive is the following:

```
error: invalid types ‘float[int]’ for array subscript
```

**Question**

What exactly am I doing wrong, and how can I accomplish this task?

Comment: You are allocating only rows for 2D array and not the columns. You have to `new float[MATRIX3_DIMS]` for columns also.

Comment: There are multiple things wrong here but the syntax error is because you need to replace '(*ret)' with just 'ret' -- you're trying to dereference a ptr-to-ptr type three times when it can only be dereferenced twice.

Comment: @iammilind also `( *ret )[ i ][ j ]` dereferences a `float **` 3 times. `ret` is a `float**`, `*ret` is a `float*` and `(*ret)[i]` is a `float`. You can't do `float f; f[0];` but that's basically what you do and what the compiler complains about. Also I'd recommend that you allocate the matrix with `new float[height*width]` and access it with `mat[i%width+j*width]` or write a small wrapper class and override the subscript operator.

Comment: I hope you are planning on releasing the memory afterwards.

Comment: The real question is why is a member function called Matrix3f::Transpose() returning a reference to something to other than another Matrix3f object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ret is a pointer to pointer to float.  When you dereference it, like this: `(*ret)`, you get a pointer to float.  When you take an index on that, like this: `( *ret )[ i ]`, that gives you a float.  When you take an index on that, like this: `( *ret )[ i ][ j ]`, well, you're trying to index off of a float.  That's not legal.

Putting my disgust for this style of coding aside, the first thing you're doing wrong is you are not allocating the sub-arrays.  The compiler error though, refers to the error I illustrated in the first paragraph.  Just remove the dereferencing of ret to fix that.  You end up with this:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < MATRIX3_DIMS; i++ )
{
    ret[i] = new float[MATRIX3_DIMS];
    for ( int j = 0; j < MATRIX3_DIMS; j++ )
    {
        ret[ i ][ j ] = matrix[ i ][ j ];
    }
}
```

This is totally not exception safe though, and you should be using a class that properly manages memory in an exception safe way, like `std::vector`.